# I am trying to add a sticky navigation to my website

Tags: html, css, navigation, hamburger-menu

Here is the code snippet. I am trying to add a sticky navigation to my website: https://amrutabuge.com/

Adding the code shows the navigation however it's not sticky and the hamburger nav overlay doesn't show up with a background.

This is the code

HTML

```
<!-- navigation bar -->
    <div class="navhamburger">
        <!-- title or logo to be deleted later-->
        <a href="#" class="logo">Title</a>
       
        <!-- hamburger icon -->
        <input class="side-menu" type="checkbox" id="side-menu"/>
        <label class="hamburger" for="side-menu">
            <span class="hamburger-line"></span>
        </label>
        
        <!-- menu -->
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Google Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Google Search</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">Spotify</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Spotify Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Squarespace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Other work</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
* Navigation */

.navhamburger{
    background-color: gray;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Logo */
.logo{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
}

/* Nav menu */
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 

}

.menu a{
    padding: 30px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    margin:  0 auto;
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu a:hover{
    /*background-color: gray;*/
    opacity: 60%;
}



/* Menu Icon */
.hamburger{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}/* Style label tag */

.hamburger-line {
    background: black;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 24px;

} /* Style span tag */

.hamburger-line::before,
.hamburger-line::after{
    background: black;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
}
.hamburger-line::before{
    top: 5px;
}
.hamburger-line::after{
    top: -5px;
}

.side-menu {
    display: none;
} /* Hide checkbox */


/* Toggle menu icon */
.side-menu:checked ~ nav{
    max-height: 100%;
}
.side-menu:checked ~ .hamburger .hamburger-line {
    background: transparent;
}
.side-menu:checked ~ .hamburger .hamburger-line::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top:0;
}
.side-menu:checked ~ .hamburger .hamburger-line::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:0;
}
```

Adding the code shows the navigation however it's not sticky and the hamburger nav overlay doesn't show up with a background.

Answer (score 0):

At the following to the css code for it to work

```
body {
   position: static;
}
```

View Codepen Fix: https://codepen.io/Grifting/pen/abQegoW